# Can a HashMap hold a binary tree?

Tags: java

An example:
A normal HashMap takes a key and a value (key k, value v)
if k = "somestring", v = 1(some value);
so instead of the above can i have say:
k= some index value, v = to some binary tree?
is this possible?

Comment: The value objects can be any java object. Keys need to have proper `hashCode` and `equals` implemented, but values don't.

Comment: there is a `TreeMap`. you sure you want to use `HashMap` not `TreeMap` \

Comment: @roottraveller `TreeMap` is just a map implementation using red/black trees. It's not actually holding trees as values.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, I know that. I was just pointing out - does he really need a Tree or a `TreeMap` can solve his use case.

Comment: I'm not too sure. I was thinking as hashmaps have O(1) access / search and then have a tree stored within to make a full serach more efficient as tree search is O(long n) in the worst case?